# Return nodes who are connected by a common set of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

Is there a way in Neo4j, using either cypher or gremlin, to return a list of nodes that have a common set of nodes between them?

An example would be

```
Person1-[KNOWS]->Friend1
Person1-[KNOWS]->Friend2
Person1-[KNOWS]->Friend3

Person2-[HATES]->Friend2
Person2-[HATES]->Friend3
```

I want to start at `Person1` and say, "Find me the people who hate all the people I know", which should return `Person2` since `Person1` knows `Friend2,Friend3` and `Person2` hates `Friend2,Friend3`.

I've started by finding the connection,

```
START
    person=node(1)
MATCH
    person-[KNOWS]->friend<-[HATES]-enemy
RETURN 
    enemy
```

but I can't seem to find a way to express it such that the Person has to hate ALL the friends.

Can this be done in Cypher?

Answer (score 1):

the syntax should be as follows, but i can't get rid off the aggregate error message

```
START
    person=node(1)
MATCH
    person-[r1:KNOWS]->friend<-[r2:HATES]-enemy
WHERE
    count(distinct r1)=count(distinct r2)
RETURN 
    enemy
```

edit: maybe this is closer:

```
START
    person=node(1)
MATCH
    person-[r1:KNOWS]->friend<-[r2:HATES]-enemy, person-[r3?:KNOWS]-enemy
WITH
    person, enemy, count(distinct r1) as  rk1, count(distinct r2) as rk2,r3
WHERE 
    r3 is null
    AND
    r1=r2 
RETURN 
    enemy
```

Comment: That's almost perfect. Unfortunately it won't return the proper results because `r1` is a `KNOWS` relationship and `r2` is a `HATES` relationship.

Comment: that does not matter, since the person who hates all your friends has to have the same amount (count) of relationships of type HATE you have of type KNOWS. thus, comparing count(r1) and count(r2) should be an appropriate equation.