# Using Neo4j from within delphi

Tags: delphi, api, neo4j

any idea how to interact with Neo4J from delphi 2010?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Neo4J offers a [REST API](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current). So you can use any HTTP client library for Delphi (Indy, Synapse...) and use HTTP GET / POST / DELETE do read / insert / delete records.

Comment: thanks @mjn do you know any third-party that made such interface? I think its easy enough to do it via synopse RESTful and JSON abilities, but i need to test the theory of GraphDB before getting involved.

Comment: the REST API is therefore to do the job. it's up to you which client you will use with delphi. there is no reason why the "theory of graphDB" should not work.

Comment: @ulkas thank you, I like you posts on grapgDB but I couldn't get familiar with the cypher queries like this _[example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182830/return-nodes-who-are-connected-by-a-common-set-of-nodes/11306808#11306808)_.    
if you know a good Cypher tutorial please refer to it, and I'm not talking basics but real life scenarios like for instance customers, contacts, invoices, orders, etc..  
_Thank you_

Comment: I think this one is good: http://video.neo4j.org/ybMbf/querying-stanley-kubrick-an-intro-to-cypher/ albeit a bit outdated.

Comment: i'm sorry ob, i'm not aware of any good practical tutorial except the official documentation. i went through it, set-up the server and played with it a bit. combining with my previous math-graph knowledge i adopt the cypher syntax. i'm working on one commercial solution, so when it will be working properly and will speed up our systems i will write about it for sure, but until then i'm just an enthusiast and no guru

Answer (score 1):

REST API implemented via Synopse library is the direct answer to this question.
Peter`s video was my favorite introduction to GraphDB.
Thank you guys,
**Love SO**